# How to get the minus sign in the shape builder tool ?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was just going through the tutorial **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuHGRwcR-Ho)** and at 2:43 this guy uses the shape builder tool, so in my AI , i have the following:

[image]

Now i am getting the plus sign below my cursor , but inorder to follow the tutorial i need the minus sign , how do i get the minus sign in the shape builder tool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while using the Shape Builder tool.